# Where to place StrictMode code within an Android app

Tags: java, android

here is my situation:

Have am developing an Android app with 5 Activities:

1. SplashActivity
2. MainActivity
3. ActivityA
4. ActivityB
5. ActivityC

The app starts with the splash screen, then displays the main activity.  From there the user can select activity A,B or C.

I wanted to test the entire app with StrictMode, both thread and VM policies.  I know that for an app with only one activity, the code for both policies would go at the top of onCreate() in that one activity.  There are many examples of this on the 'net, but none with more than one activity.

I am thinking for my particular situation, both the VM and thread policies would go at the top of onCreate() in the SplashActivity, since that is the very beginning of the app.  I am thinking this would cover the VM policy for the entire app.

In addition, the thread policy would go at the top on onCreate() in each of the remaining activities, in order to detect problems in any of them.

My question here is: Is this the proper way to go about testing with StrictMode?  If not, what is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to apply the policy to the whole app then you need to do it when your app is initialized. Subclass Application and overrride YouApplication.onCreate() and set you policy here. Dont forget to define in your manifest

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I understand I can do that, but suppose for example I wanted to use StrictMode in most but not all of the activities - In that case, where would the VM and thread policies have to go?  That is really what I am trying to get at.

Comment: Activity.onCreate() or Activity.onStart()

Comment: Thanks again, I don't think I am describing my question properly.  Please look at my list of activities in my original question.  Suppose I want to use StrictMode in SpashActivity, ActivityB and ActivityC.  Is this true: To implement this, I would put the VM policy in SplashActivity.onCreate() - because that covers the entire VM, and I would put the thread policy in SplashActivity.onCreate(), ActivityB.onCreate() and ActivityC.onCreate()??  I am looking for which activitires the code needs to be added.  I hope that clarifies what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes you are right, adding it in an Activity context wouldnt affect the whole VM instance. So you add to all of them. 
PS; Try making those classes extend a Base class that handles the policy to avoid the clutter in repeating yourself over and over